# Difference in Ide's (Memory Optimization in Python)

Tags: python, data-structures, cpython

I was working with DataStructures Lab. and I found out that:

```
a = 2
b = 2
print(id(a)) #1632496144
print(id(b)) #1632496144
```

Both a and b variables have same id
but, when I did this

```
x = 500
y = 500
print(id(x),id(y))
```

it's written here that if the range will exceed from **-3 to 256**, it will give **different memory locations**.

My question is that why these IDE's are giving different results?

In JUPYTER NOTEBOOK the output is this:
`2999875658288 2999875658256` different memory locations

while In VS CODE the output is this:

`1495642916912 1495642916912` same memory locations

Answer (score 1):

Python (CPython, actually) caches some small, frequently used values like these in a cache so it does not has to create and destroy these objects all the time.

Here is a short description about this on the [C API reference](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong).

Also, sometimes Python will do the same for strings and other objects, so for example you can do the same with the string "a" like this: `print(id("a"), id("a"))` and you get the result `140301498960896 140301498960896`.

Keep in mind that CPython does not guarantee this behavior, this is just an implementation detail and it is not part of the language design itself.

Under Jupyter if I run the following cell: `id(500), id(500)`, I get `(139638184229584, 139638184229584)` but if I run the same in the next line, that will return a different pair of numbers (the values are still the same, though). Jupyter is probably keeping these values alive and that is causing this behavior.

I think CPython keeps objects in small data cache below 256 bytes, but I'm not sure about this number not I could find a reference for it. If I find a reference, I will edit my answer.